# Find product which installed some file

Tags: windows-installer

**Using msi engine (newer than 3) on Windows (XP+, 7, 2k3):**

Is there a way to find the already installed product which installed some file, like on Linux using rpm or deb package managers?

Linux (with deb):

```
$ apt-file search autoexpect
expect-dev: usr/share/doc/expect-dev/examples/autoexpect.1.gz
expect-dev: usr/share/doc/expect-dev/examples/autoexpect.gz
expect-tcl8.3: usr/share/doc/expect-tcl8.3/examples/autoexpect
expect-tcl8.3: usr/share/doc/expect-tcl8.3/examples/autoexpect.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Windows Installer handles resources through [components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It doesn't know about actual files or registry entries.

To determine if a specific component is installed you can use the [MsiGetComponentState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370113%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Sadly, you are right. That's one from a long list of reasons I prefer Unix over MS Win.